# How to expand correctly the last UITableViewCell of an UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have an UITableView with expandable cells, each cell is compound of a stack and I show or hide some elements of this stack for expanding or collapsing the cell.

Here is a GIF with the **expected behaviour**:

[image]

And this is the piece of code used to change the size of a cell:

```
func expandCel(_ cell: MyCell) {
        if let arrowButton = cell.arrowUpDownButton {
            if arrowButton.isSelected {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                cell.stackHides.alpha = 0
            }) { [weak self] (_) in
                arrowButton.isSelected = false
                cell.stackHides.isHidden = true
                cell.isCompressed = true
                self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self?.tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        } else {
            cell.stackHides.alpha = 0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                arrowButton.isSelected = true
                cell.isCompressed = false
                cell.stackHides.isHidden = false
            }) { [weak self] (_) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    cell.stackHides.alpha = 1
                    self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self?.tableView.endUpdates()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but **after** some cells are expanded and **the last cell of the table reaches the bottom of the screen**, something unexpected happens...

The **first time** I tap the button of the **last cell** for expanding it, it expands but **collapses immediately**.

After this first expansion attempt, when I expand or collapse any cell (including the last one) seems to work but I get another undesired effect, a weird **scroll**.

If I collapse cells until the last cell is not anymore at the bottom of the screen, the table works nice.

Here is another GIF to explain better the **undesired behaviour**:

[image]

Comment: did you `check self.tableview.reloadData()` instead of `begin` and `endUpdate` ?

Comment: Try to reload only the index-paths for visible rows.

Comment: None of this work, thanks anyway.